# Kendo grid removes tick mark?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have below kendo grid. I want remove 'Tick mark' and 'Done' after asyn upload.
How to do that? Following code removes the text 'Done' but tick mark is still visible.

**Kendo upload control:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
    .Name("files")       
    .Messages( m => m.Select("Browse"))     
    .Async(a => a
        .Save("SaveAttachment", "Document")
        .Remove("Remove", "Document")
        .AutoUpload(true)
     )
     .Events(events => events
         .Success("onSuccess")
     )
     .Multiple(false)
) 

$("#files").kendoUpload({
    multiple: true,
    async: {
        saveUrl: "...",
        removeUrl: "...", 
        autoUpload: false
    },
    localization: {
        // Override built-in text "Done"            
        headerStatusUploaded:"",
        statusUploaded:""
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: Can you please add code sample in jsfiddle?

Comment: In your code you are creating two kendo upload widgets and it can causes a lot of problems. To access your already defined widget you should use code like `var upload = $("#files").data('kendoUpload')`.

Answer (score 2):

To hide all messages ('Uploading...' and 'Done') and icons you can use simple css:

```
.k-upload .k-upload-status.k-upload-status-total {
    display: none;
}
```

If you want to hide just 'Done' and tick icon as you said - you can do it by using javascript events:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
    .Name("files")
    .Messages(m => m.Select("Browse"))
    .Async(a => a
        .Save("Submit", "Watchdog")
        .AutoUpload(true)
     )
     .Events(events => events
         .Success("onSuccess")
         .Select("onSelect")
         .Complete("onComplete")
     )
    .Multiple(false)
)

<script>
    function onSelect(e) {
        e.sender.element.closest('.k-upload').find('.k-upload-status.k-upload-status-total').show();
    }

    function onComplete(e) {
        e.sender.element.closest('.k-upload').find('.k-upload-status.k-upload-status-total').hide();
    }
</script>
```